# how to select an element that in the html code is not close to the element that is hovering

Tags: css

basically I have a structure similar to this one:

```
<a class="elementHovering"  >
    <span dropdownToggle mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="nav-link waves-light font-weight-bold texto_menu" mdbWavesEffect>Visión</span>
</a>
<div class="other_class">
  <span>
        <div class="elementMove">
        </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

how can I indicate by means of css that when I hovering in the element with class "`elementHovering`" that the element with class "`elementMove`" moves?

this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/64y1ftrx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+`:

```
.elementHovering:hover + div.other_class .elementMove {
  top: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: heyyy thanks! an ultimate question, in this case, how can do it the same? https://jsfiddle.net/64y1ftrx/1/  the same effect when the cursor is hover of  .elementHovering class?

Comment: @unusuario I think you are missing a `position: relative` rule for the `.elementMove`

Comment: `.elementHovering:hover ~ div.elementMove`? I don't understand your comment exactly, but this works in your second fiddle